# Android screen issue

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm having an issue with android screens for certain emulators.  I get the following:

[image: android screen issue]

This happens only with certain emulators settings and specifically on samsung galaxy 2 devices.

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: figured out why this is occurring, I added the following to disallow screen capture: `getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);`  once it was removed things went back to normal.  Follow up question, anyone know why this happens?

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming related issue. So consider moving your question to the android blogs, or try to reinstall your android SDK.

Comment: how would it not be a programming issue?  I programmed the app not to allow screen capture using the above code.  It caused an issue.  Hopefully this can help someone else who has the same issue.  Re-installing the sdk has no merit in solving this issue, removing the line of code did resolve it.

Comment: The feature and the problem you're referring to is hardware related. The code you've placed tells the program not to use the hardware feature. But the question "why the fuzzy screen happens if the hardware feature is used" is not a programming question, rather it is the display driver-android platform communication. Try using an actual device and try to screen capture, you'll get a "Couldn't capture screenshot" type of message. Hope this clarifies the reason of my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem on Android 2.x devices (only) when I've added this code to my abstract base activity. I'm using this code to disable screenshots of my app in the Android 4.0 Recent apps list.

Finally I've found that this code works safely at least on Android 4.x devices. So my solution to this issue was to check if I'm running on Android 4.0 or later:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
    getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
}
```

Comment: This wont protect your app from getting screenshots taken on devices pre 4.0 though.

Comment: Fortunately these are quite rare. And I also did not have a chance to test this on 3.x devices. So I rather stayed safe then sorry (receive another crash reports). In my case I did not observe this bug on 2.x emulator. It crashed only on real devices.